# C# Asynchronous socket server doesn't receive response from Java client

Tags: c#, java, state, asyncsocket

Bear with me, this is a complex question and it's a long piece of code, but I've been pulling my hair out for about two weeks trying to get this to work, frustration level is very-very high.  Any help is appreciated!

I've got a sockets based Java server & client that uses an XML based database.  I'm replacing the server with a C# based one that talks to a MySQL database.  The client will remain as-is until it can also be replaced, probably late next year at the earliest, so consider it translucent box (at best), and immutable.

I need to be able to support up to around a dozen or so of the Java clients at a time with the new server, maybe a couple dozen if we expand our facility.

It took quite some time to get the client to respond to a server, but the hard-coded server does communicate with the client, although in a very brute force manner.  It was my proof of concept, and I thought it'd be relatively simple to transform the code into an asynchronous server using the [**MSDN example**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) & off I'd go.  That was about two weeks ago.  We held a code review last Friday to help me get the hard coded stuff into the async server.  I have achieved some success, the client responds to it's initial contact with the username as it's supposed to, but any further communication ceases there (it's supposed to send an XML based query, and the server respond with an XML based response).

Here's the Program flow:

Start server;

Start client;

Server send: "`Login:`" but this could be literally anything

Client send: "`USERNAME`"

Server send: "`ACCEPTED`"

Server send: "`ACCEPTED`" (*no idea why this is necessary like this, but the client doesn't respond to the first server send, and I can't change it*).

Client send:  `<PCBDataBaseCMD><Search><PCBID>33844</PCBID></Search></PCBDataBaseCMD>`

Server send:

```
<Executing/>
<PCBDatabaseReply>
    <SearchResult>
        <SBE_PCB_Data PCBID='33844'>
            <Creation ActionID='e2a7' User='DELLIOTTG:192.168.1.214' Date='2013-01-23T13:16:51' PCBID='33844'>
                <PCBDrawing>10376A</PCBDrawing>
                <AssemblyDrawing>41528F</AssemblyDrawing>
                <Vendor>PCA</Vendor>
                <PONumber>99999</PONumber>
            </Creation>
            <Assignment ActionID='e2c1' User='DELLIOTTG:192.168.1.228' Date='2013-01-23T15:30:00' PCBID='33844'>
                <SBESerialNumber>04104743</SBESerialNumber>
            </Assignment>
        </SBE_PCB_Data>
    </SearchResult>
</PCBDatabaseReply>
```

This XML will show up in the client as expected.

Reset & wait for next client request.

Here is the hard-coded server (this will compile as-is):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

class MyTcpListener
{
    public static void Main()
    { 
        Int32 port = 8955;
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.137");
        TcpListener server = null;   
        server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
        server.Start();
        Socket socketForClient = server.AcceptSocket();
        NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);
        System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream);
        System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
        string response1 = @"<Executing/>
            <PCBDatabaseReply>
                <SearchResult>
                    <SBE_PCB_Data PCBID='33844'>
                        <Creation ActionID='e2a7' User='DELLIOTTG:192.168.1.214' Date='2013-01-23T13:16:51' PCBID='33844'>
                            <PCBDrawing>10376A</PCBDrawing>
                            <AssemblyDrawing>41528F</AssemblyDrawing>
                            <Vendor>PCA</Vendor>
                            <PONumber>99999</PONumber>
                        </Creation>
                        <Assignment ActionID='e2c1' User='DELLIOTTG:192.168.1.228' Date='2013-01-23T15:30:00' PCBID='33844'>
                            <SBESerialNumber>04104743</SBESerialNumber>
                        </Assignment>
                    </SBE_PCB_Data>
                </SearchResult>
            </PCBDatabaseReply>";
        try
        {
            while(true) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Client connection... ");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("poke"); //this can literally be anything, just something to let the client know the server's there
                streamWriter.Flush();
                string userName = streamReader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(userName);
                streamWriter.WriteLine("ACCEPTED");
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.WriteLine("ACCEPTED");
                streamWriter.Flush();
                string buffer = string.Empty;
                bool sendFlag = true;
                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                char[] c = new char[512];
                while (sendFlag)
                {               
                    streamReader.Read(c, 0, c.Length);
                    buffer += string.Join("", c);
                    streamReader.Read(c, 0, c.Length);
                    buffer += string.Join("", c);
                    Console.WriteLine(buffer);
                    if(streamReader.Peek() < 0 )
                    {
                        sendFlag = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Apparently not at the end?");
                    }
                }                       
                Console.WriteLine("RECEIVED: " + buffer);
                //}
                Console.WriteLine("SEND: " + response1);
                streamWriter.Write(response1);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch(ObjectDisposedException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ObjectDisposedException: {0}", ex);
        }
        catch(SocketException e)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            server.Stop();
            streamReader.Dispose();
            streamReader.Close();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I've transferred the code into the async server, but I have to admit a less than perfect understanding of how all the pieces work together, and how the state object works to direct traffic.  I ***think*** communication may be breaking down in the SendCallBack() module because I'm not sending a "stop receive" message, or maybe a "continue with transmission" message, I'm not sure.

Here is the asynchronous server (this **will not compile**, it's missing a lot of MySql, command line processing, etc. code in the interest of shortening it up).

```
    public static IPAddress IpAddress { get; set; }
    private static readonly ManualResetEvent AllDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public static IPEndPoint GetIpEndPoint()
    {
        IpAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.FirstOrDefault(addr => addr.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork");
        if (IpAddress != null)
        {
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IpAddress, CommandLineOptions.Port);
            return localEndPoint;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public class StateObject
    {
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        public const int bufferSize = 1024;
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string XmlContent { get; set; }
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        public StreamReader sr;
        public StreamWriter sw;
    }
    public static void StartListening(IPEndPoint localEndPoint)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);
            while (true)
            {
                AllDone.Reset();
                Console.WriteLine("PCBDatabaseServer online awaiting a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, listener);
                AllDone.WaitOne();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();
    }
    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            AllDone.Set();
            Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
            NetworkStream nwsHandle = new NetworkStream(handler);
            StateObject acbState = new StateObject
                {
                    workSocket = handler,
                    sw = new StreamWriter(nwsHandle) {AutoFlush = true},
                    sr = new StreamReader(nwsHandle)
                };
            acbState.sw.WriteLine("poke");
            handler.BeginReceive(acbState.buffer, 0, StateObject.bufferSize, 0, ReadCallback, acbState);
            acbState.UserName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(acbState.buffer);
            Console.WriteLine(acbState.UserName);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            StateObject rcbState = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
            rcbState.sw.Write("ACCEPTED");//**this double call is required, the client has two ReadLine() statements, pretty sure the first write could be anything, and it only sees the second one, but I can't change the client**
            rcbState.sw.Write("ACCEPTED");
            string testMeToo = string.Empty;//this is where I'm trying to capture the XML data from the client, which should end up in rcbState.XmlContent, but I'm flailing here trying to get this to work.
            bool sendFlag = true;
            char[] c = new char[512];
            while (sendFlag)
            {
                rcbState.sr.Read(c, 0, c.Length);
                testMeToo = string.Join("", c);
                rcbState.sr.Read(c, 0, c.Length);
                testMeToo += string.Join("", c);
                Console.WriteLine(testMeToo);
                if (rcbState.sr.Peek() < 0)
                {
                    sendFlag = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Apparently not at the end?");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("RECEIVED: " + testMeToo);
            rcbState.workSocket.BeginReceive(rcbState.buffer, 0, StateObject.bufferSize, 0, AcceptCallback, rcbState);
            rcbState.XmlContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rcbState.buffer);
            Console.WriteLine("XML: " + rcbState.XmlContent);
            rcbState.XmlContent += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rcbState.buffer);
            Console.WriteLine("XML: " + rcbState.XmlContent);
            int bytesRead = rcbState.workSocket.EndReceive(ar);
            string content = string.Empty;
            //**things break down here, you can ignore this if statement**
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    rcbState.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcbState.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                    content = rcbState.sb.ToString();
                }
                if (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \nData : {1}", content.Length, content);
                    Console.WriteLine(content);
                    Send(rcbState.workSocket, content);
                }
                else
                {
                    rcbState.workSocket.BeginReceive(rcbState.buffer, 0, StateObject.bufferSize, 0, ReadCallback, rcbState);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        NetworkStream nwsHandle = new NetworkStream(handler);
        StateObject sendState = new StateObject
            {
                workSocket = handler,
                sw = new StreamWriter(nwsHandle) {AutoFlush = true}
            };
        sendState.sw.Write(data);
    }
    //here is where I think the communication is breaking down, I think the client may be waiting for some signal to tell it to send the next bit, but I can't figure out what that may be.
    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
            NetworkStream nwsListen = new NetworkStream(listener);
            NetworkStream nwsHandle = new NetworkStream(handler);
            StateObject scbState = new StateObject
            {
                workSocket = handler,
                sw = new StreamWriter(nwsHandle) { AutoFlush = true },
                sr = new StreamReader(nwsListen)
            };
            int bytesSent = scbState.workSocket.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);
            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Here are some links I've researched, the first is a related question I wrote  while back:
[Source-less black box client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144539/change-jar-file-without-the-source)

[C#<> Java socket communications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078417/c-sharp-java-socket-communication)

[How to write a scalable TCP/IP based server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869744/how-to-write-a-scalable-tcp-ip-based-server?rq=1)

[C# High Performance Socket Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to consider:

1. Your AllDone.Wait() is going to block your accept thread while you carry on a conversation with the client.  This kind of defeats the purpose of async I/O as you want the server to go back to listening for connections as soon as it accepts a connection, otherwise your processing is serialized.
2. BeginReceive(...) will return immediately and you are assigning data to from the read buffer to a variable when the read may not be complete.
3. In your receive callback it appears you are issuing more async reads (BeginReceive).  Not sure this is what you intend since you are already running in a thread separate from your server's main accept thread.  You may want to consider using rcbState.workSocket.Receive(...) instead of BeginReceive(), which by the way completes back to your accept callback which should be for accepting connections not completing reads.  Thus, it appears the logic is all wrong.

So my overall suggestion is that once you get into your Accept callback use synchronous reads and writes on the new socket you get as it seems, from what I can tell, you have a series of client/server interactions to complete a "transaction".  There seems to be no value in doing additional async read/writes once you accept a connection from a client.  You are just confusing yourself by doing async reads/writes at that time.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll be the first to admit I'm confused by this!  I'll poke at this some more today & see if I can make use of your comments.  I think you may have hit on the problem with the transaction with regards to async & sync reads & writes.  I certainly hope so, I'm very much ready to be done with this.